# Error Attempting to Call a WPF Form From Console App

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, console-application

I have a console Application and I need to occasionally launch a WPF form depending on the parameters. I and trying the following:

```
if (arg == "/C")
{
    System.Windows.Application application = new System.Windows.Application();
    application.Run(new EJConfig.MainWindow());
}
```

The problem is that when I go to add a reference to System.Windows, it doesn't show up in the list of .NET components, and without it I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Do you need to interact with the WPF application or could you launch-and-forget? If so, consider building it as .exe and launching using the Process class

Comment: try adding the assemblies `PresentationCore` and `PresentationFramework`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding:

```
using System.Windows;
```

To the top of the c# file? You may also need these assemblies:

> Assembly:  PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)
>
> Assembly:   PresentationCore (in PresentationCore.dll

Check it out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx)

Comment: He needs both add the PresentationCore assembly and PresentationFramework assembly for this to work.

Comment: I added `PresentationCore` to the answer

Comment: I don't think the `using` would help. The error message says it doesn't recognize that there *is* such a thing as `System.Windows`, so putting it in a `using` instead of a fully-qualified name won't change anything. It's a problem with a missing assembly reference, not a missing `using` directive.

Comment: I did say that he may need to add the PresentationFramework and Presentation Core assemblies.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add the `PresentationFramework` and `PresentationCore` assemblies to your project.

The `System.Windows.Application` class is located in the PresentationFramework assembly, but you'll also need PresentationCore for it to work.

source: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing additional references besides System.Windows. I don't know which are required. You could find out by creating a default application and check the references listed.